# How do I set combobox's background color on selected item?

Tags: winapi, combobox, background-color, selecteditem

I have a owner-draw combobox where I'd like to recreate the standard behavior, i.e., that blue background color over the current selected item. I've tried set X when the WM_DRAWITEM message is received without luck like this:

```
    case WM_DRAWITEM:
    {
      LPDRAWITEMSTRUCT b = (LPDRAWITEMSTRUCT) lParam;
      if(b->itemAction & ODA_FOCUS)
      {
        SetBkMode(b->hDC, TRANSPARENT);
        SetBkColor(b->hDC, GetSysColor(COLOR_HIGHLIGHT));
        DrawFocusRect(b->hDC, &b->rcItem);
        return (INT_PTR) TRUE;
      }
```

Example of behavior I'm refering to:

[image]

What it does look like currently:

[image]

full code:

```
#pragma comment(lib, "user32.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "Comctl32.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "Gdi32.lib")
    
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#define UNICODE
#define _UNICODE

#include <windows.h>
#include <Commctrl.h>
#include <assert.h>

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
void SetDefaultFont(HWND hwnd);
HFONT LoadSystemDefaultFont();
void DrawBorder(HDC hdc, RECT *rect);
void DrawLine(HDC hdc, LONG x1, LONG y1, LONG x2, LONG y2);
void freeBrushes();
HBRUSH getBrushAt(int index);
void drawColorRect(HDC dc, RECT *editRect, int colorIndex);

HINSTANCE g_hinst;
HFONT hDefaultSystemFont;

#define COUNTOF(a) (sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]))
#define LIST \
    X(L"Black", RGB(0, 0, 0)) \
    X(L"Red", RGB(255, 0, 0)) \
    X(L"Blue", RGB(0, 0, 255)) \
    X(L"Green", RGB(0, 128, 0)) \
    X(L"Yellow", RGB(255, 255, 0))

#define X(a, b) a,
const wchar_t *items[] = { LIST };
#undef X

#define X(a, b) b,
const int colorCodes[] = { LIST };
#undef X

HBRUSH brushes[COUNTOF(items)];

int WINAPI wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                    PWSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow) {

  
    HWND hwnd;
    MSG  msg;
    WNDCLASSW wc = {0};
    wc.lpszClassName = L"Application";
    wc.hInstance     = hInstance ;
    wc.hbrBackground = GetSysColorBrush(COLOR_3DFACE);
    wc.lpfnWndProc   = WndProc;
    wc.hCursor       = LoadCursor(0,IDC_ARROW);

    g_hinst = hInstance;

    RegisterClassW(&wc);
    hwnd = CreateWindowW(wc.lpszClassName, L"Combo box",
                  WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE,
                  100, 100, 270, 170, 0, 0, hInstance, 0);  


    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) {
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    
    DeleteObject(hDefaultSystemFont);
    freeBrushes();

    return (int) msg.wParam;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, 
        WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {

    static HWND hwndCombo;

    switch(msg)
    {
        case WM_CREATE:
        {
            hwndCombo = CreateWindow(L"Combobox", NULL, 
                WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | CBS_DROPDOWNLIST |
                CBS_OWNERDRAWFIXED | CBS_AUTOHSCROLL | WS_VSCROLL | WS_HSCROLL,
                10, 10, 100, 110, hwnd, NULL, g_hinst, NULL);
            SendMessage(hwndCombo, CB_SETMINVISIBLE, 5, 0);
            SetDefaultFont(hwndCombo);
            for (int i = 0; i < COUNTOF(items); ++i)
            {
                SendMessage(hwndCombo, CB_ADDSTRING, 0, (LPARAM) items[i]);
            }
        }
        break;

        case WM_DRAWITEM:
        {
          LPDRAWITEMSTRUCT b = (LPDRAWITEMSTRUCT) lParam;
          if(b->itemAction & ODA_FOCUS)
          {
            SetBkMode(b->hDC, TRANSPARENT);
            SetBkColor(b->hDC, GetSysColor(COLOR_HIGHLIGHT));
            DrawFocusRect(b->hDC, &b->rcItem);
            return (INT_PTR) TRUE;
          }
          else if(b->itemAction & ODA_DRAWENTIRE)
          {
            if(b->itemAction & ODA_FOCUS)
            {
                DrawFocusRect(b->hDC, &b->rcItem);
            }

            if(b->itemID != -1)
            {
                drawColorRect(b->hDC, &b->rcItem, b->itemID);
                DrawText(b->hDC, items[b->itemID], -1, &b->rcItem, DT_CENTER | DT_VCENTER | DT_SINGLELINE);
            }
            else
            {
                //drawColorRect(b->hDC, &b->rcItem, 0);
                DrawText(b->hDC, L"Select", -1, &b->rcItem, DT_CENTER | DT_VCENTER | DT_SINGLELINE);
            }

            return (INT_PTR) TRUE;
          }
        }
        break;

        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            break; 
    }

  
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
}


HFONT LoadSystemDefaultFont()
{
  if(hDefaultSystemFont == NULL) {
    NONCLIENTMETRICS ncm;
    ncm.cbSize = sizeof(NONCLIENTMETRICS);
    SystemParametersInfo(SPI_GETNONCLIENTMETRICS, sizeof(NONCLIENTMETRICS), &ncm, 0);
    hDefaultSystemFont = CreateFontIndirect(&ncm.lfMessageFont);
  }
  return hDefaultSystemFont;
}


void SetDefaultFont(HWND hwnd)
{
    SendMessage(hwnd, WM_SETFONT, (LPARAM) LoadSystemDefaultFont(), TRUE);
}

void drawColorRect(HDC dc, RECT *editRect, int colorIndex)
{
    assert(colorIndex >= 0 && colorIndex < COUNTOF(brushes));
    assert(editRect != NULL);

    RECT rt = {0};
    rt.left = editRect->left + 2;
    rt.top = editRect->top - 2;
    rt.right = editRect->right / 5;
    rt.bottom = editRect->bottom - 2;
    InflateRect(&rt, -1, -1);
    DrawBorder(dc, &rt);
    //FrameRect(dc, &rt, getBrushAt(0));
    FillRect(dc, &rt, getBrushAt(colorIndex));
}

void DrawLine(HDC hdc, LONG x1, LONG y1, LONG x2, LONG y2)
{
    MoveToEx(hdc, x1, y1, NULL);
    LineTo(hdc, x2, y2);
}
    
void DrawBorder(HDC hdc, RECT *rect)
{
    DrawLine(hdc, rect->left, rect->top, rect->left, rect->bottom);
    DrawLine(hdc, rect->left, rect->top, rect->right, rect->top);
    DrawLine(hdc, rect->right, rect->top, rect->right, rect->bottom);
    DrawLine(hdc, rect->left, rect->bottom, rect->right, rect->bottom);
}

HBRUSH getBrushAt(int index)
{
    assert(index >= 0 && index < COUNTOF(brushes));
    HBRUSH b = brushes[index];
    if(b == NULL) {
        int code = colorCodes[index];
        brushes[index] = CreateSolidBrush(code);
        b = brushes[index];
    }
    return b;
}

void freeBrushes()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < COUNTOF(brushes); ++i){
        DeleteObject(brushes[i]);
        brushes[i] = NULL;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To draw the selected item with a different background and text colour, you need to check the `itemState` member of the given `DRAWITEMSTRUCT` (`lParam`) argument for the `ODS_SELECTED` flag.

Something like the following:

```c
    case WM_DRAWITEM:
    {
        LPDRAWITEMSTRUCT b = (LPDRAWITEMSTRUCT) lParam;
        SetBkMode(b->hDC, TRANSPARENT);
        if(b->itemState & ODS_SELECTED) // Selected ...
        {
            SetTextColor(b->hDC, GetSysColor(COLOR_HIGHLIGHTTEXT));
            FillRect(b->hDC, &b->rcItem, (HBRUSH)(COLOR_HIGHLIGHT+1));
        }
        else // Not selected ...
        {
            SetTextColor(b->hDC, GetSysColor(COLOR_WINDOWTEXT));
            FillRect(b->hDC, &b->rcItem, (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+1));
        }
        DrawText(b->hDC, items[b->itemID], -1, &b->rcItem, DT_CENTER | DT_VCENTER | DT_SINGLELINE);
        // Check for focus ...
        if(b->itemAction & ODA_FOCUS)
        {
            DrawFocusRect(b->hDC, &b->rcItem);
        }
        return (I
NT_PTR) TRUE;
```

Note: When using a system colour for the `hbr` parameter of your `FillRect` call, you **need to add one to the value**. From the [documentation for `FillRect`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-fillrect):

> ...If specifying a color value for the hbr parameter, it must be one
> of the standard system colors (the value 1 must be added to the chosen
> color).

Comment: Oh, you're right. I was checking for focus, probably due to tiredness. But even switching to select, I still can't make that background to change. Does your code worked in your machine? I'm dealing with `WM_DRAWITEM` like this https://pastebin.com/jMP7S2bP

Comment: It would take rather a lot of coding for me to test the presented solution on my machine! Generally, my projects these days wrap the message handling and drawing in MFC. However, work through things, one step at a time. Maybe you need to actually draw the rectangle in the specified colour (with a `Rectangle(b->hDC, ...)` call after selecting an appropriate brush?

Comment: It seems the way to go. You put me in the right direction, thanks! I have  to redraw pretty much everything, fill the rectangle, set the text color, and redraw the color box and draw the text when depending on the `b->itemState & ODS_SELECTED` the code looks like this https://pastebin.com/W8H1efnD now about the colors, does `COLOR_HIGHLIGHTTEXT` and the associated backcolor, use system's default, such as https://i.stack.imgur.com/A5tvT.png? on my machine it isn't so, look like this: https://imgur.com/42kNLXT

Comment: According to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getsyscolor) `COLOR_HIGHLIGHT` and `COLOR_HIGHLIGHTTEXT` should be the system defaults. I think you also need to call `SetBkColor(b->hdc, COLOR_HIGHLIGHT)` and `SetBkMode(b->hdc, OPAQUE)` before your `DrawText` call.

Comment: It still not working, I'm getting same colors. I think it's getting the colors of windows pre-visual-style. I'll try luck with `GetThemeSysColor()` and whatnot. Anyway, you give me the right answer, just change that `SetBkColor` to `            FillRect(b->hDC, &b->rcItem, (HBRUSH) COLOR_HIGHLIGHT);` and I'll accept the answer. For some reason, `SetBkColor` doesn't work there so I did paint the whole rectangle.

Comment: @Jack OK - edited following your suggestion (but see the stuff about the `+1` in the calls). Without that `+1`, then the `COLOR_HIGHLIGHT` value (13) will be interpreted as `COLOR_APPWORKSPACE` (12) - which is often the grey value your image shows.

Comment: wow, it worked fine! Thanks! Why is `COLOR_*` enumerated that way? backward compatibility?

Comment: @Jack I *think* it's so that you can pass a `NULL` (zero) value as the `hbr` parameter, and it's not interpreted as `COLOR_SCROLLBAR` (which is #defined as 0).

Comment: Just one thing about the code, I'm using a `CBS_DROPDOWNLIST` and it sends a -1 in the b->itemID. **I think** -- not confirmed yet, it's to draw the default text that appear in the combobox, not the very first item, so without the `if(b->itemID != -1)` before draw the text, it results in an error (memory violation) my final code look like this https://pastebin.com/kxNDp6VL This additional comment is just to make the code perfect for those with same issue as me, that may came later